# Error when calling WSDL soap method - Microsoft.Web.Services.SoapFormatException

Tags: php, wsdl

I'm new to SOAP and web services, and am trying to connect to a supplier WSDL SOAP provider using PHP. I've successfully connected to the API, and was able to pull down the listing of methods. However when I try to make a basic call to one of the functions, I am getting this error returned back from the server:

> Microsoft.Web.Services.SoapFormatException: The input was not a valid SOAP message because it has either wrong name which is Envelope or wrong namespace which is http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope. at Microsoft.Web.Services.SoapEnvelope.PostLoad() at Microsoft.Web.Services.SoapEnvelope.Load(Stream stream) at Microsoft.Web.Services.WebServicesExtension.BeforeDeserializeServer(SoapMessage message)

This is my web service call:

```
$soapConnection = new SoapClient("http://webapi.testsupplier.com/gvitawapi.asmx?WSDL",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'uri' => "http://webapi.testsupplier.com/"));   
var_dump($soapConnection->GetAllTestDataXML());
```

This is the response xml from the suppliers documentation. I'm not sure if I am supposed to be doing anything with this:

```
POST /gvitawapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webapi.testsupplier.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAllTestDataXML xmlns="http://webapi.testsupplier.com/" />
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Any thoughts that you can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to get this working by switching over to SOAP 1.1 in my connection. For whatever reason that works, however switching to 1.2 causes this same error. It also helped me to debug by enabling exceptions to get the full response text.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to pass parameters along in your call for a webservice like this, it wasn't quite as straight forward as I had expected. I assumed parameters would be passed in an array, with the values in there such as:

    `$soapConnection->GetAllTestDataXML(array('id' => 5678));`

Instead, the parameters have to go into a parent array, with the key 'parameters':

    `$param = array('id' => 5678);`
    `$soapConnection->GetAllTestDataXML(array('parameters' => $param));`